# Reading and parsing CSV files

Tags: parsing, unit-testing, scala, reinventing-the-wheel, csv

This is my first real attempt at a Scala program. I come from a predominantly Java background, so I'd like to know if the program sticks to Scala conventions well.

Is it well readable or should it be formulated differently?  To me, there is a lot of lines in the main function which doesn't quite bode right.

It is functioning and I can provide my JUnit tests to prove it. Not all tests pass as those dealing with whitespace are now different.

I didn't want to use any parsing library or support as that doesn't help me learn the core of the language.

```
package com.wesleyacheson

import scala.io.Source
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class CSVReader2(source: Source) {

  val QuoteChar = '"'
  val LF = '\n'
  val CR = '\r'
  val Separator = ','

  def readAll(lines:List[List[String]] = Nil):List[List[String]] = {
    if (source.hasNext) {
      return readAll(readLine()::lines)
    }
    return lines.reverse;
  }


  @tailrec final def readUntilQuote(buffered: AnyRef with BufferedIterator[Char], partial:String = ""):String = {
    val char = buffered.next()
    val next = if(buffered.hasNext) buffered.head else ""
    (char, next) match {
      case (QuoteChar, QuoteChar) => readUntilQuote(buffered, partial + buffered.next()) //We've read both charachters so skip
      case (QuoteChar, _) => partial
      case _ =>  readUntilQuote(buffered, partial + char)
    }
  }

  def readLine():List[String] = {
    val buffered = source.buffered
    @tailrec def readLine(tokens:List[String] , partialToken:String):List[String] = {
      val finished = {() => (partialToken::tokens).reverse}
      if (!buffered.hasNext) return finished()
      val char=buffered.next()
      val subsequentChar = if (buffered.hasNext) buffered.head

      (char, subsequentChar) match {
        case (QuoteChar, x) if x != QuoteChar =>
          readLine(tokens, partialToken + readUntilQuote(buffered))
        case (QuoteChar, QuoteChar) =>
          buffered.next();
          readLine(tokens, partialToken + QuoteChar)
        case (Separator, _) =>
          readLine(partialToken::tokens, "")
        case (CR, LF) =>
          buffered.next(); finished()
        case (CR, _) =>
          finished()
        case (LF, _) =>
          finished()
        case _ =>
          readLine(tokens, partialToken + char)
      }

    }

    readLine(Nil, "");
  }

}
```

If interested, the unit tests are here:

```
package com.wesleyacheson

import org.junit._
import Assert._
import scala.io.Source

class CsvReader2Test {

   val simpleSource = Source.fromString("""abc,def,ghi
 jkl, zzz""");
   val quotedFields = Source.fromString("foo bar, \"foo bar\"");

   @Test def VerifyReaderPassedMustNotBeNull() {
     val source: Source = null;

     try {
       new CSVReader(source)
       fail("Should have thrown exception")
     } catch {
       case e: IllegalArgumentException => //Expected
     }
   }

   @Test def VerifyReadAllReturnsAStringList() {
     assertTrue("Expected a List[String]", new CSVReader2(simpleSource).readAll().isInstanceOf[List[String]]);
   }

   @Test def VerifyNumberOfReadLinesAreCorrect() {
     assertEquals(2, new CSVReader2(simpleSource).readAll().size)
   }

   @Test def VerifyFirstLineContainsExpectedValues() {
     val firstLine = new CSVReader2(simpleSource).readAll().head
     println(firstLine)
     assertEquals("Checking the number of tokens in the first line", 3, firstLine.size)
     assertTrue("Checking that the line contains " + "abc", firstLine.contains("abc"))
     assertTrue("Checking that the line contains " + "def", firstLine.contains("def"))
     assertTrue("Checking that the line contains " + "ghi", firstLine.contains("ghi"))
     assertFalse("Checking that the line does not contain" + "jkl", firstLine.contains("jkl"))
   }

   @Test def verifyBothQuotedFieldsAreTheSame() {
     val line = new CSVReader2(quotedFields).readAll().head;
     assertEquals("Checking that the number of tokens in the first line", 2, line.size);
     assertEquals("foo bar", line(0));
     assertEquals("foo bar", line(1));
   }

   @Test def verifySimpleQuotedValueIsUnchanged {
     println(new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"foo bar\",")).readLine()(0))
     assertEquals("foo bar", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"foo bar\",")).readLine()(0))
   }

   @Test def verifyDoubleQuotesAreConvertedToQuote {
     assertEquals("\"foo bar\"", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"\"foo bar\"\",")).readLine().head)
   }

   @Test def verify3QuotesAreTreatedAsDoubleQuotesWithinSection {
     assertEquals("\"foo bar\"", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"\"\"foo bar\"\"\",")).readLine().head)

   }

   @Test def verifyQuotedCommasAreReturned {
     assertEquals(",", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\",\",")).readLine().head)
   }

   @Test def verifyLeadingWhiteSpaceIsRemoved {
       assertEquals("abc  def", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("   abc  def")).readLine().head)
   }

  @Test def verifyTailingWhiteSpaceIsRemoved {
    assertEquals("1", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("1    ")).readLine().head)
  }

  @Test def verifyQuotedLeadingWhitespaceIsPreserved {
    assertEquals("   1", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"   1\"")).readLine().head)
  }

  @Test def verifyQuotedTailingWhitespaceIsPreserved {
    assertEquals("1   ", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"1   \"")).readLine().head)
  }

  @Test def verifyQuotedBlankLinesArePreserved{
    assertEquals("first\n\rsecond", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("\"first\n\rsecond\"")).readLine().head)
  }

  @Test def verifyCellsAreInTheRightOrder{
    val returned = new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("first,second")).readLine()
    assertEquals("first", returned(0));
    assertEquals("second", returned(1));
  }

  @Test def verifyRowsAreInTheRightOrder{
    val returned = new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("first\nsecond")).readAll()
    assertEquals("first", returned(0)(0));
    assertEquals("second", returned(1)(0));
  }

  @Test def verifyNewLineCarriageReturnIsOnlyTreatedAsOneBlankLine{
    val returned = new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("first\n\rsecond")).readAll()
    assertEquals("first", returned(0)(0));
    assertEquals("second", returned(1)(0));
  }

  @Test def verifyReadsUntilFirstQuote {
    assertEquals("abc\"defg", new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("")).readUntilQuote(Source.fromString("abc\"\"defg\"hi\"jklmnop").buffered ))
  }

  @Test def verifyThrowsExceptionIfNoQuoteFound {
    try {
    new CSVReader2(Source.fromString("")).readUntilQuote(Source.fromString("a").buffered)
      fail()
    } catch {
      case e => //expected
    }
  }
 }
```

What I see when I look at this coming from a Java viewpoint. String concatenation isn't usually done with `+`. However I don't see how to use a string buffer and keep it semi functional.

The program isn't a functional program. I don't think this could have been avoided using a source. Pure functional programming would have meant that I'd have to make concessions like converting the entire input to a string outside and passing that in which isn't practical.

I don't like the argument-less anonymous function but I don't know what else to do for it.

```
val finished = {() => (partialToken::tokens).reverse}
```

I've been told that a lazy `val` may be more appropriate for this, and I tend to agree.

It may be better for extendability if I returned a list of token objects (or is this my Java head interfering?)

I wonder if any traits could be mixed in to make it more rich. If there was a trait dealing with 2-dimension tabular data for instance.

The buffered iterator was a bit of a cheat. My original was far longer until I added that. Feels like maybe I've skipped a bit of learning for the sake of convenience.

Comment: @Jamal I can't agree with the tag edits. This may be a case of reinventing the wheel but the purpose of it is learning. The focus of the question isn't about how to prevent that. Similarly for csv tag, and the unit-testing. The question isn't about that. The purpose isn't to read a CSV. The tests were only in the question to prove the criteria of code review. The body changes are fine, but I'd like to revert the title and tags.

Comment: Then you may make these changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things, going from smallest to the more significant.

1. Try to avoid using return. It isn't idiomatic, and for [good reason](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-018). So instead of writing `if (cond) return a; return b` you should prefer `if (cond) a else b`
2. Unless I'm missing anything, in `readUntilQuote`'s signature `buffered` should be of type `BufferedIterator[Char]` instead of `AnyRef with BufferedIterator[Char]`. The `AnyRef` there doesn't do anything useful.
3. You can use `Source` and still have functional code. Specifically, try looking at [`Source.getLines()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.io.Source). It returns an `Iterator[String]` that is lazily-evaluated but can still be used functionally almost like other collections (you can `map`, `fold`, `filter`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see that I've rewritten a bit of your code. For readabilities sake my first suggestion is to attempt to make your function definitions and their parameter lists consistent with the [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/). Next, I would also move the `@tailrec` annotation one line above the function for which it is intended. Lastly, I would rename your inner function such that people reading your code can quickly see that it is an inner 'Helper' function.

```
    def readLine(): List[String] = {
      // ...

      @tailrec
      def readLineHelper(tokens: List[String], partialToken: String): List[String] = {
        // function body
      }

      readLineHelper(Nil, "")
    }
```

You also mentioned that you didn't like your `finished` function. It appears to me that you can improve its implementation in one of two ways. At first glance it seems that `readLineHelpers` parameters `partialToken` and `tokens` are never altered throughout the course of the function, in other words they are immutable values. If this is the case than `finished` can be declared as a reference to data:

```
    val finished = (partialToken :: tokens) reverse
```

If, however, there is some state change to `partialToken` or `tokens` then you will need to declare `finished` as you originally did, as a function value but with the following syntax:

```
    val finished = () => (partialToken :: tokens) reverse
```